# How to integrate fcm in chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to setup firebase messaging from laraval server to chrome extension but while setting up receiver in chrome extension service worker, I am getting following error

code: "messaging/only-available-in-window"
message: "Messaging: This method is available in a Window context. (messaging/only-available-in-window)."
stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a Window context. (messaging/only-available-in-window).\n    at t.requestPermission (chrome-extension://naidknbafhicaoafmfimlpmolidhnjno/assets/js/firebase-messaging.js:122:403)\n    at chrome-extension://naidknbafhicaoafmfimlpmolidhnjno/background.js:19:15"
[[Prototype]]: Error
I am looking for solution from last 2 days but did not  find anything. Is there any way to setup firebase messaging in chrome extension  maninefst v3 or anyother alternative?

Comment: As the error says you can't use this script in a service worker, so report the bug to FCM support or find an existing report, which should already exist. Meanwhile, open an html file of your extension in a new window/tab (or an [extension iframe](/a/25100953) in a web page) and use FCM there.

Comment: but how I will be able to receive messages after window is closed?

Comment: ManifestV3 is great, isn't it? You'll have to keep the window open.

Comment: ok thanks can you help me with one more thing   messaging.requestPermission is not a function with v9 sdk what should i do with it?

Comment: I don't know, try asking in that thread.